# Odoo Inherited view not styled

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-8

i want to inherit one view from another in **Odoo v8**. The first view has the id: ***form_authority_information*** and the inherited view has the id: ***form_authority_information_construction_law***

Here's the code for ***form_authority_information***

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="form_authority_information">
        <field name="name">view.name</field>
        <field name="model">company.authority_information</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    <group colspan="4" id="content">
                        <group colspan="2" col="2" id="general">
                            <separator string="General" colspan="2"/>
                            <field name="related_field"/>
                            <field name="information_date"/>
                            <field name="information_medium" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_finished', '=', True)]}" />
                            <field name="is_finished"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

[image: Correct formatting in master view]

And for ***form_authority_information_construction_law***:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="form_authority_information_construction_law">
        <field name="name">Construction Law</field>
        <field name="model">company.authority_information.construction_law</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="form_authority_information"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <group id="general" position="after">
                    <separator string="Construction Law" colspan="2"/>
                    <field name="construction_law_type"/>
                    <field name="building_area_type"/>
                    <field name="zoning_name" attrs="{'invisible':[('construction_law_type', '=', 'qualified')]}"/>

                </group>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

[image: Wrong formatting in inherited view]

The data inheritance works fine. I have all the fields i want to see in the inherited view. The problem is, that it does not style the inherited view. For the master view everything is displayed in a "sheet"-environment but for the inherited view the order is another and the sheet is not displayed. Also the "attr" property doesn't work.

Does anyone know the solution for this strange behaviour?

Update: Images
Update2: Is an external id necessary to work properly?

Update3: Python code
**models.py**

```
class company_authority_information(models.Model):
    _name = 'company.authority_information'
    # other fields...

class company_authority_information_report_committee(models.Model):
    _name = 'company.authority_information.report_committee'
    _inherit = 'company.authority_information'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove data from the view, it will added by odoo engine it self.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You wrote wrong model name there, need to write parent model name in inherited view.
`<field name="model">company.authority_information</field>`

Comment: If i do this i get the following error: `Error details:
Field zoning_name does not exist` So it seems that the model should be the inherited model. Otherwise I can't access the fields which live only in the inheritance.

Comment: Could you please paste your python code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following,

```
class company_authority_information(models.Model):
    _name = 'company.authority_information'
    # other fields...

class gut8_authority_information_report_committee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'company.authority_information'
```

If you provide _name then it will create table for that, so when you inherit any model then either you keep the same _name as _inherit or do not specify _name in case of _inherit exist there. restart server and upgrade module if not work.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="form_authority_information_construction_law">
        <field name="name">Construction Law</field>
        <field name="model">company.authority_information</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="50" />
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="form_authority_information"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <group id="general" position="after">
                    <separator string="Construction Law" colspan="2"/>
                    <field name="construction_law_type"/>
                    <field name="building_area_type"/>
                    <field name="zoning_name" attrs="{'invisible':[('construction_law_type', '=', 'qualified')]}"/>
                </group>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. It was the `_name`.

Comment: Always remember one thing that whenever you want to add or extend something into your parent model then in the view `<field name="model">` must have the parent model name. it will add the content of view to the model. So if you give there child model then it won't gives you any indication because syntactically it's not wrong, it's logical point.

Comment: Now i have the problem that it inherits ALL the views not only the one i want to inherit. How do i solve that?

Comment: Can you please clarify more ?, actually what happen and what you want to do.

Comment: I now have authority_information, authority_information_report_committee and authority_information_construction_law. The view is every time a combination of all three views. Seems it doesn't know when to apply which view.

Comment: If your all the view inherit this same parent view then all the things will bring together if all the modules are installed in which you have added that views. We can help you better if you clarify your aim with few more details. And if possible ask new question with UI images so no need to explain more via text.

Comment: Ok, let's say we have A,B and C. A is the master which helds the data which is needed in B and C. So if i look at view B I want to see A and B and if i look at C I want to see A and C. So: B inherits from A, C inherits from A. I want views for B and C, (every time including A)

Comment: Obviously this happen. You need to use the attrs or domain to filter or invisible fields as per requirements. And If you have separate action for each then you can pass your logic to hide show fields with context.